# Display a specific category in a focused area of my site

Tags: posts, categories, themes, code

I've been trying to change the code of my WordPress site. Rather than showing "trending posts" which is determined by `post_views_count`, I simply want to show posts from a certain category. The code, as it stands is:

```php
if ( !function_exists( 'getCrunchifyPostViews' ) ) {
function getCrunchifyPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
  }
}

if ( !function_exists( 'setCrunchifyPostViews' ) ) {
function setCrunchifyPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I simply get it to show posts of a certain category? (FYI the category_name is 'review')

Comment: is this not possible with a post query block?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell - you're talking to a complete novice here, buddy!

Can you point me in the direction to any decent resources where I can pick up some advice on post query blocks?

Comment: post query blocks aren't a coding/PHP feature, you can find them in the block inserter alongside paragraphs lists embeds etc. The official handbook docs on wp.org should cover these. They're also a part of the latest default theme twenty twenty two

Comment: also, you shared the code for getting/setting view counts but no information about the code that displays trending posts itself